# how to copy and change data?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do I change the second set of data without affecting the first? thank you.

```
first = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]]

second = first.copy()

second[0][1] = 0

print(first)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `deepycopy`.

You are currently doing [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy) which constructs a new compound object and then inserts references into it to the objects found in the original. Whereas [`deepycopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> first = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
...         [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]]
>>>
>>> second = deepcopy(first)
>>> first
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
>>> second
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
>>> second[0][1] = 0
>>> first
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
>>> second
[[1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
>>>
```